# How to use custom factory with Structuremap?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, structuremap, structuremap3

I have a scenario where my class has dependency on two services. However I am using provider pattern and have a custom factory that returns me instances of these services reading from the app.config file.

Here is sample scenario code that I want to implement

```
public class ClassA
{
     public ClassA(IServiceA serviceA, IServiceB)
     {
         // ServiceA and ServiceB are instantiated through a factory class
     }

     public ClassA(IServiceFactory factory)
     {
         // I want to use this constructor and use this factory and call the above constructor
     }
}
```

In the above code my ClassA needs ServiceA and ServiceB but I want to use my factory to create instances of these classes, thus I created another constructor with dependency on the factory class. Now from structure Map I want to create a configuration that uses this constructor of each class and resolves the factory correctly. I do not want to define mapping for each class manually, rather create a configuration rule that will resolve each class correctly.

I can't figure out how this should be done? Kindly give some suggestion.

Comment: Are you still having difficulties with this?

Comment: @JoeMighty Yes please if you can assist me that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at using the factory method registration to have StructureMap resolve IA and IB and return a new instance of ClassA calling the constructor directly.